# react ui flickering state update settimeinterval

Tags: reactjs

hi i am updating timer state on settimeinterval

it is causing ui flickering

and also flickering is causing on some browsers like chrome, safari

```
let [showTimer, setShowTimer]  = useState(false);
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState("00")
const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState("00")
const [hours, setHours] = useState("00")
const [days, setDays] = useState("00");
useEffect(() => {
countDown()
return () => {
  window.clearInterval(timeIntervalRef.current)
 }
}, [showTimer]) 



 
  function countDown() {
    // this is the count down for the closet on sale
        const endTime = new Date(selectedVariant['negotiated']['endTime']).getTime();
         timeIntervalRef.current = setInterval(function(){
         const nowTime = new Date().getTime();
         let secondsLeft = Math.round((endTime - nowTime) / 1000);
         if (secondsLeft <= 0) {
          setTimer({ 
             show : false,
             timeLeft: {}
           })
        clearInterval(timeIntervalRef.current);
  }

  

  setDays(("0" + Math.floor(secondsLeft / 86400)).slice(-2));
  secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 86400;
  setHours(("0" + Math.floor(secondsLeft / 3600)).slice(-2));
  secondsLeft = secondsLeft % 3600;
  setMinutes(("0" + Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60)).slice(-2));
  setSeconds(("0" + secondsLeft % 60).slice(-2));
  // let updatedTimer = { show:true,  timeLeft:updatedTime };
  // setTimer(updatedTimer);
    }, 1000)
```

}

i am intiliazing timer on condition that is show timer i have not included that code on that condition i am calling  countDown function

html code

```
{
      showTimer ? <div className={`mx-3 border-top text-center py-3 mb-2 `} >
       <h6 className="text-pink1"><img src="https://cdn1.coutloot.com/webAssets/icons/flash.png" /> Hurry Up</h6>
       <div className={` d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center text-pink1`}> 
           <span className={styles.timer_box} > { days?.charAt(0) } </span>
           <span className={styles.timer_box} > { days?.charAt(1) } </span>
           <span className="text-pink1 f16 "> : </span>
           <span className={styles.timer_box} > { hours?.charAt(0) } </span>
           <span className={styles.timer_box} > { hours?.charAt(1) } </span>
           <span className="text-pink1 f16"> : </span>
           <span className={styles.timer_box} > { minutes?.charAt(0) } </span>
           <span className={styles.timer_box} > { minutes?.charAt(1) } </span>
           <span className="text-pink1 f16"> : </span>
           <span className={styles.timer_box} > { seconds?.charAt(0) } </span>
           <span className={styles.timer_box} > { seconds?.charAt(1) } </span>
       </div>
       <div className="text-pink1 f14 py-2"> 
           {selectedVariant.negotiated.offerText}
       </div>
   </div> : null
   }
```

is there any workaround

Comment: Can you update question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) component code example? You've got the minimal part down, but it's incomplete and unreproducible. You could try reducing the state complexity and simply store seconds and derive the hours and minutes in the render result.

Comment: @DrewReese there is only state variables and i am updating and displaying them with help of jsx

Comment: Well, this is react so that much is easy to assume. We need to see how you are instantiating state, what else is happening in the component lifecycle, and how you are rendering your UI, to even begin debugging.

Comment: @DrewReese please see updated